# How can i store chat history in Android

Tags: android, xmpp

I am working on an XMPP client app that sends and receives IM using ASmack library. I want to store the Chatting history among the users. This history must be persistent until i clear the chat by clicking a button.

What is the best possible way to maintain the chat history and any snippets will be of great help.

Comment: are u able to save the previous chat list in ur application....can u please help me in this..i also want to save the prvious chat list but iam not able to save....

Comment: How are you trying to store the data? SQLite, SharedPreferences or as simple objects?

Comment: The way I have implemented is, store the fromuserid, touserid, and the message in a table. When the activity is called, I fired the query and retrieved all the messages on the basis of userid's and populated the adapter of the list view. I am also clearing the database table when the activity is killed so that the database doesnot get too heavy

Comment: If you dont need the data to be persisted for very long, then you can maintain the data using datastructures like Hashmaps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple Sqlite database comes to mind. You could then save all history of all chats for as long as you need. And selectively erase one chat session and not another.

See : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

And you'll find a lot of easy tutorial to follow along on the interweb.

Comment: Is going SQLite way is the only solution? Does other chat apps like Gtalk, Facebook etc use sqlite to store chat sessions?

Comment: Gtalk,Facebook save their data in server side not in local data base.

Comment: You could reinvent the wheel : - XML, JSON or make your own text format and save to a file. - Save to SharedPreferences(watch the size though). - Save on your server. It's just that Sqlite was made for storing data easily and efficiently so this is the easy route.